# Is Microsoft Drivers 2.0 for PHP for SQL Server Still Around Somewhere?

Tags: php, sql-server

So version 3.0 is at [Microsoft's download site](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098).  Furthermore, there is a line on that page saying

> Please note that the download link for the 2.0 Driver will be deprecated in the near future

Yeah, that's wonderful and all, but under requirements

> PHP 5.3.6 or PHP 5.4

I am using 5.2.x and I really should not be that high for the application I am designing.  I just can't find a copy of the php_sqlsrv.dll file I need from googling, but I am sure it is still around somewhere.  Anyone know where I can get a copy?

Comment: PHP5.2 is old .... Just read http://www.php.net/archive/2010.php#id2010-12-16-1 (and note, that this is __2010__): "This release marks the end of support for PHP 5.2. All users of PHP 5.2 are encouraged to upgrade to PHP 5.3."

Comment: @KingCrunch The version is forced on me, it is out of my hands

Comment: @demongolem ... university or government ? :(

Comment: @demongolem If you are using a shared host (or something similar): Change to a more responsible one. or tell your administration, that they are probably relying on unsecure and inefficient software.

Comment: There's nothing wrong in legacy software that gets the job done. It'd be crazy to request a server upgrade every time a new feature is required.

Comment: This isn't just about features.  It happens that Microsoft themselves put a *lot* of effort into making PHP better on Windows starting with version 5.3.  It really is going to be worthwhile to try upgrading if you can.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the PHP docs page for [PDO_SQLSRV](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlsrv.php), there's a download for the version you require.

[`SQLSRV20.EXE`](http://download.microsoft.com/download/C/D/B/CDB0A3BB-600E-42ED-8D5E-E4630C905371/SQLSRV20.EXE) (download.microsoft.com)

Comment: Download from Web-Archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20111125204240/http://download.microsoft.com/download/C/D/B/CDB0A3BB-600E-42ED-8D5E-E4630C905371/SQLSRV20.EXE

Answer (score -1):

It can be found here
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296170(v=sql.105).aspx

Below this line *Version 2.0 of the driver requires Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Native Client. Click on the appropriate link below:*

[Download the X86 package](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=188400&clcid=0x409)

Comment: No. Unfortunately, that link is for the "Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Native Client" package. The OP wants the "Microsoft Drivers for PHP for SQL Server" that work with PHP 5.2.